# Is it possible to separate or split original images (or videos) from a blend image (or video)

Tags: transformations, blending, fourier-transform, blender

The title says it all.  Blended image or video contains multiple image or video blended on top of each other. I am looking for any software or tools that can separate the original images or videos.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on blendmode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @joojaa is there cases where it is possible? What tools are there?